# Insert Multiple columns from Multiple parameters on SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014, multiple-columns, sql-insert

I receive from a webpage the following pipe separated parameters

```
@RecepientID     varchar(20)='1|2'

@LocationID      varchar(20)='7|8|9|10'

@BranchID        varchar(20)='1|5|9'
```

I need to add into columns all posible combinations as follows

```
RecipientID   LocationID   BranchID
```

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS (version included)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question nor any indication of research, effort, ... . Not even expected results. Just "I need".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like SQL Server code. Starting from SQL Server 2016 you could use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @RecepientID varchar(20)='1|2';
DECLARE @LocationID varchar(20)='7|8|9|10';
DECLARE @BranchID varchar(20)='1|5|9';

-- INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT s1.value AS Recipient, s2.value AS Location, s3.value AS Branch
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@RecepientID, '|') s1,
STRING_SPLIT(@LocationId, '|')s2 ,
STRING_SPLIT(@BranchId, '|') s3;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06043ebb3ca9a42e3e94e39c7b0a3eb0)**

---

The better idea is to pass arguments as [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately I use SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the solution for SQL 2016, I created a function to handle the split and solved my problem for SQL 2014 with:

```
DECLARE @RecepientID varchar(20)='1|2';
DECLARE @LocationID varchar(20)='7|8|9|10';
DECLARE @BranchID varchar(20)='1|5|9';

create table #t (col1 smallint,col2 smallint,col3 smallint)

INSERT INTO #t(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT s1.nvalue, s2.nvalue , s3.nvalue
FROM  dbo.insSplit(@RecepientID, '|') s1,
      dbo.insSplit(@LocationID, '|') s2 ,
      dbo.insSplit(@BranchID, '|') s3;

select * from #t
```